# Non english characters getting messed up while saving in MySQL table

Tags: mysql, ruby

I am trying to save 'non english' characters in mysql table. But when I check the table data, it shows some junk characters.

Text before save:

`КУЛИНАРНЫЕ ФЕСТИВАЛИ В ЕВРОПЕ Нужно Путешествовать ВКУСНО!...`

Text after save in mysql:

`ÐšÐ£Ð›Ð˜ÐÐÐ ÐÐ«Ð• Ð¤Ð•Ð¡Ð¢Ð˜Ð’ÐÐ›Ð˜ Ð’ Ð•Ð’Ð ÐžÐŸÐ• ÐÑƒÐ¶Ð½Ð¾ ÐŸÑƒÑ‚ÐµÑˆÐµÑÑ‚Ð²Ð¾Ð²Ð°Ñ‚ÑŒ Ð’ÐšÐ£Ð¡ÐÐž!... http://t.co/JdXw8Od3`

Table column Settings:

- varchar(1024)
- utf-8 general-ci

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running `SET NAMES utf8` before your insert statements. Hope that helps.